# DynDNS and the incontrovertible badauth response

Tags: c#, api, dyndns

I'm trying to use the DynDNS API to validate user-supplied DynDNS credentials, and [the documentation](http://dyn.com/support/developers/api/perform-update/) says that [the 'badauth' response](http://dyn.com/support/developers/api/return-codes/) is meant for exactly that.
The idea being that I can automate an update with the user credentials and look for the badauth response and use that to detect incorrect credentials, which sounds perfect.
The problem is that the only response I ever get is badauth. When I send credentials that should be good (since they're currently working for login and all) I get a badauth response. Here's my code:

```
   try
   {
     string target = string.Format( "http://{0}:{1}@members.dyndns.org:8245/nic/update?hostname={2}&myip={3}",
      HttpUtility.UrlEncode( DynDnsUserName ), HttpUtility.UrlEncode( DynDnsPassword ), HttpUtility.UrlEncode( DynDnsURL ), ip );
     HttpWebRequest request = WebRequest.Create( target ) as HttpWebRequest;
     request.Method = "GET";
     request.UserAgent = company + " - " + model + " - " + firmware;
     HttpWebResponse response = request.GetResponse() as HttpWebResponse;
     Stream reply = response.GetResponseStream();
     StreamReader readReply = new StreamReader( reply );
     string returnCode = readReply.ReadToEnd();
     Trace.WriteLine( "We've validated the provided DynDNS credentials, response received: " + returnCode );
     return !returnCode.Contains( "badauth" );
   }
   catch (WebException webEx)
   {
     Trace.WriteLine( "WebException thrown: " + webEx.Message );
     if (webEx.Response != null)
     {
      Stream reply = webEx.Response.GetResponseStream();
      StreamReader readReply = new StreamReader( reply );
      Trace.WriteLine( "Actual response: " + readReply.ReadToEnd() );
     }
   }
```

No matter the credentials I use, I keep getting a thrown WebException "Remote server returned an error: (401) Unauthorized" with a response body of badauth.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

{0}:{1}@... won't do with webrequest.

Your target is just "http://members.dynd....", and you do something like

```
NetworkCredential myCredentials = new NetworkCredential(username,passwd);

request.Credentials = myCredentials;
```

Comment: Hmm, the [Uri](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.uri.userinfo.aspx) class and the [WebRequest.Create](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0aa3d588.aspx) method suggests that it should work, but that could very well be an incorrect assumption on my part.  I'll look into that, thanks.

Comment: Fantastic, you were absolutely correct!  Even though the API documentation itself consistently uses the Uri-embedded-credentials method, it doesn't actually work.  Switching to the more specific method of specifying credentials made everything work perfectly.

Comment: Had this very problem just a few weeks ago.